# "Moral Victory" Trophy Prologue Knockout

Tags: achievements, thief

There is a trophy/achievement in Thief called "Moral Victory" with the description "Finish the game without a single kill or knockout".
Does the tutorial knockout in the prologue not count towards this, or is there a way in the prologue to avoid the knockout?

Comment: I don't know for sure but it probably doesn't count. When you go to custom difficulty options there is one for no kills or knockouts, and it specifically says the tutorial doesn't count for that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot proceed through the game without knocking out that one particular guard in the prologue, as you will automatically receive a game over screen if you take too long to take him down.

Because of that, he does not count towards the trophy.

There is one easy way to prove it: Play the game with custom difficulty and select the "*No Kills or Knockouts*" option. Since you do not get a game over screen after knocking that guard out, you can tell he doesn't count.

Comment: Yes, looking back I could have thought of that myself. Additionally, there are statistics under the player progession tab, where you can see how many enemies you killed/knocked out. This is a good way to see if someone got harmed by accident. Also, according Prima Games' online guide, only chapter missions count towards the trophy, meaning in The City and in Client missions you can kill and knock out people as you please. I did not try this myself though.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's the prologue and you're forced to do it, I'm certain it doesn't count to the achievement or trophy. You can't harm anyone from this point on.